# Wordpress trailing slash in permalink address causes a 404

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

For some reason my Wordpress install now requires a trailing slash after the page name.

For instance http://somedomain.com/page-name (404's)

Yet http://somedomain.com/page-name/ (serves the correct page)

I wonder whether this is just because of a stricter Apache server on the remote server i've just uploaded it too, compared to that of my local environment.

Needless to say though it would be great to get a suggested fix in place :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below links.

[wordpress mu 404 without end slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846751/wordpress-mu-404-without-end-slash)

http://yamz.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/trailing-slash-in-wordpress-permalink-causes-404-error-in-ie/

It will work , sure..